# MySQL Select Query Picking Up The Wrong Record

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, html-table

So i've recently created a section on my website that displays a table populated from a MySQL database. Since users log in, there are certain records I don't want other users to see but some users I do want to see. So i've setup a security level system. It's working fine so far. One this page, i run an if statement to see if the users have a security level of 4 and if they do, i run a SELECT * query based on their name. So the query is

```
SELECT * WHERE `assignedTo` = '$username'
```

Which in theory is working, it doesn't give me any errors nothing and i have error reporting turned on. This is the error code i've got in place;

```
//Error Reporting
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

However I have one record in the database for test purposes and the `assignedTo` field contains 'Example1' now when i login as 'Example2' I can still see this record that is assigned to 'Example1'. I've run a var_dump() and it shows me the following;

```
object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) {
 ["queryString"]=>
 string(68) "SELECT * FROM `customerLeads` WHERE `assignedTo` = 'Example2' "
}
```

So the query is right, that is how it should run but it shouldn't be displaying the record because `assignedTo` is equal to 'Example1' not 'Example2'.

Here is my code for that webpage;

```
<?php  
//Session Start
session_start();

//Error Reporting
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);


require 'includes/conn.php';
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$user_security = $_SESSION['user_security'];

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || !isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    //User not logged in. Redirect them back to the login.php page.
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("You must be logged in!");
            window.location.href = "login.php";
        </script>
    <?php
}

$user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];

if ($user_security == 4) {
 $customerList = $salesConn->query("SELECT * FROM `customerLeads` WHERE `assignedTo` = '$user_name' ");
}

if ($user_security == 0 OR 1) {
  $customerList = $salesConn->query("SELECT * FROM customerLeads");
  }
 var_dump($customerList);
?>
```

And then this is my table where i display the data;

```
  <table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Full Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Telephone</th>
    <th scope="col">Vehicle of Interest</th>
    <th scope="col">Budget</th>
    <th scope="col">P/X Vehicle</th>
    <th scope="col">P/X Reg</th>
    <th scope="col">P/X Finance</th>
    <th scope="col">P/X Settlement</th>
    <th scope="col">Salesman</th>
    <th scope="col">Status</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <?php
  while ($cRow = $customerList->fetch()) {
    $firstName = $cRow['customerFirstName'];
    $lastName = $cRow['customerLastName'];
    $tele = $cRow['customerTel'];
    $mob = $cRow['customerMob'];
    $mail = $cRow['customerEmail'];
    $add1 = $cRow['customerAdd1'];
    $add2 = $cRow['customerAdd2'];
    $add3 = $cRow['customerAdd3'];
    $add4 = $cRow['customerAdd4'];
    $vehInterest = $cRow['customerVeh'];
    $vehChange = $cRow['customerChangeDate'];
    $vehDrive = $cRow['customerDriveDate'];
    $vehFinance = $cRow['customerFinance'];
    $vehBudget = $cRow['customerBudget'];
    $pxVeh = $cRow['customerPXVeh'];
    $pxReg = $cRow['customerPXReg'];
    $pxMile = $cRow['customerPXMileage'];
    $pxColour = $cRow['customerPXColour'];
    $pxEngine = $cRow['customerPXEngine'];
    $pxTrans = $cRow['customerPXTrans'];
    $pxFuel = $cRow['customerPXFuel'];
    $pxPrice = $cRow['customerPXPrice'];
    $pxFinance = $cRow['customerPXFinance'];
    $pxSettle = $cRow['customerPXFinance'];
    $salesman = $cRow['customerSalesman'];
    $notes = $cRow['customerNotes'];
    $status = $cRow['customerStatus'];
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td data-label="Ful Name"><?php echo $firstName." ".$lastName; ?></td>
    <td data-label="Telephone"><?php echo $tele; ?></td>
    <td data-label="Vehicle of Interest"><?php echo $vehInterest; ?></td>
    <td data-label="Budget"><?php echo $vehBudget; ?></td>
    <td data-label="P/X Vehicle"><?php echo $pxVeh; ?></td>
    <td data-label="P/X Reg"><?php echo $pxReg; ?></td>
    <td data-label="P/X Finance"><?php echo $pxFinance; ?></td>
    <td data-label="P/X Settlement"><?php echo $pxSettle ?></td>
    <td data-label="Salesman"><?php echo $salesman; ?></td>
    <td data-label="Status"><?php echo $status; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: When you run that same query manually on the database, does it also still return the unexpected result?  If so you can remove all of PHP from your debugging/question and narrow it down to just the SQL.  Also, side note, be aware that your code is open to SQL injection.  If "security" is indeed a concern, you'll want to take a look at prepared statements and query parameters.

Comment: I have run the query on database manually and it runs normally, it doens't return any results. So it's something with the PHP. Hm think i might need to start another query, as i thought using the ? in my query would be a smart move. Would it be safer to user BindValues instead?

Comment: If the same query is returning two different results then that suggests something may be amiss in the debugging.  Perhaps there's a false assumption somewhere?  Try some tests to replicate the problem on an entirely new page, including a hard-coded value or using a value from a hard-coded variable, etc.

Comment: Ah i've found an issue. So I moved where I had placed var_dump() underneath both the IF statements and when i ran it, the query was a SELECT * query. So for some reason even thought theres two IF statements and they both can't equal the same thing. The code is going into both IF statements. As the final IF statement is a SELECT * that means it's selecting everything. I've probably explained that badly, but will update my question to match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition is *always* true:

```
if ($user_security == 0 OR 1)
```

Because `1` is always a "truthy" value.  Don't think of boolean expressions in terms of how you might speak them aloud, always think of them in terms of individual distinct expressions.  In this case you have two expressions:  `$user_security == 0`, which is conditionally true or false depending on the variable; and `1`, which is always true.

You probably want this instead:

```
if ($user_security == 0 OR $user_security == 1)
```

Comment: `if ... else if` also is a good defensive programming strategy for this kind of thing.